# How to group the Sql data and their subtotal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fetching data from a SQL query. I am getting following format data

```
S.no     name          budget
---------------------------------
1      Local Travel     123
2      Global Travel    123
3      Local Expense     12
4      Current Expense   12
```

This result I am getting but what I want is, please have a look on following table format

```
Travel

    1    Local Travel     123
    2    Global Travel    123
             subtotal =   246

Expense

   3    Local Expenses    12
   4    Current Expe      12
         Subtotal   =     24
```

Please help out. I am pasting my actual query here

```
SELECT 
    concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-' , [Segment_2]),  
    T2.[AcctName],
    T5.[Name], 
    SUM(T0.[Debit]) as Actual, 
    SUM(T3.[DebLTotal]) as Budget 
FROM
    JDT1 T0  
INNER JOIN 
    OJDT T1 ON T0.[TransId] = T1.[TransId] 
INNER JOIN 
    OACT T2 ON T0.[Account] = T2.[AcctCode], OBGT T3 
INNER JOIN 
    BGT1 T4 ON T3.[AbsId] = T4.[BudgId] 
INNER JOIN 
    OBGS T5 ON T3.[Instance] = T5.[AbsId],OASC T6 
WHERE 
    T2.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' 
    AND T5.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY 
    concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-' , [Segment_2]),  
    T2.[AcctName], T5.[Name]
```

i am adding script for my tables [Please check here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dh25hz35wr6v6hc/scriptActualvsBudget.sql?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first save the result of your query in a temp table so I can have the view you showed, as in this:

```
S.no     name          budget
---------------------------------
1      Local Travel     123
2      Global Travel    123
3      Local Expense     12
4      Current Expense   12
```

In order to do that, just put an insert into `#testTable` before your `from`
like this:

```
...
 SUM(T3.[DebLTotal]) as Budget 
into #testTable
FROM
    JDT1 T0  
....
```

Then with the view above in #myTemp, I would simply write:

```
    select sno, name, budget, 
(case 
when name like '%Travel' then right(name, 6)
when name like '%Expense%' then right(name,7)
end) as NameTrim 
into #myTemp
from #testTable
```

The query above create another column called `NameTrim` to be able to differentiate between an expense or travel.

then I'm using a window function to group by:

```
select sno, name, budget,NameTrim, 
(case 
when  NameTrim like 'Travel' then 
sum(budget) over (partition by NameTrim)end)  as TravelCost,
(case 
when NameTrim like 'Expense' then 
sum(budget) over (partition by NameTrim)end)as Expense
from #myTemp
```

simulation environment:

```
create table #testTable (sno int, name varchar (50), budget int)

insert into #testTable values 
('1', 'Local Travel' , '123'),
('2', 'Global Travel' , '123'),
('3', 'Local Expense' , '12'),
('4', 'Curent Expense' , '12')

select sno, name, budget, 
(case 
when name like '%Travel' then right(name, 6)
when name like '%Expense%' then right(name,7)
end) as NameTrim 
into #myTemp
from #testTable

select sno, name, budget,NameTrim, 
(case 
when  NameTrim like 'Travel' then 
sum(budget) over (partition by NameTrim)end)  as TravelCost,
(case 
when NameTrim like 'Expense' then 
sum(budget) over (partition by NameTrim)end)as Expense
from #myTemp
```

Does this solve your problem? Seems to work just fine, the query yields:

```
sno name           budget    NameTrim     TravelCost    Expense
3   Local Expense   12       Expense       NULL            24
4   Curent Expense  12       Expense       NULL            24
1   Local Travel    123      Travel      246               NULL
2   Global Travel   123      Travel      246               NULL
```

Comment: what is #mytable ? and where to add this thing.. i am not getting .can you please mention clearly. just add this code in given query for more clearance .

Comment: If you don't get this, I highly doubt you wrote the code in your question. But in order to help you, i will explain: In your code, the one you say it's the `actual query`, after this line `SUM(T3.[DebLTotal]) as Budget ` just add `into #myTemp` this will create a temporary table in which you will have the data structured as in your first sample data, your words: `following format data`. Then you can simply use the query I suggested. Please check the name for that sno or s.no and adjust this to whatever name you have there.

Comment: its not working . giving me subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: ok, give me some min to experiment and come up with a better query

Comment: Or please see a more elegant solution, updating now

Comment: but result should be like, if its travele related then should be under Travel title alonwith their subtotal.as i elaborate in the question . please see the second table.

Comment: I understand what you want but in sql you can't do (from my knowledge, I might be wrong, but i don't think i am) row 1 then row 2 and under row 2 a 3rd row, which has no columns and only displays the subtotal. However you could display them as additional columns which have values only for the amounts calculated. That's why I wrote the query to insert `NULL` values where it's isn't being calculated. This is the closest you can probably get to your desired outcome using SQL

Comment: ok , can you explain bit more. why you used temprory tables in your query.

Comment: You could use a normal table, as in not #temp. But why would you do that to keep some intermediate steps? And I used them because I don't know if your code runs, I don't have your tables and your data, I can take the result you have given (after executing your query) and with it (inserted in a temp) I performed the calculations in order to get your expected result. I even showed you how to insert data in a #temp, and after seing the complexity of your query, you should have understood the code without any other explanation. And I believe I explained it as I would for a beginner, which you are